# Run Global NPM Module In Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

Is it possible to run an NPM module that I have installed globally in a packaged electron app? According to the docs Electron supports native node modules but doesn't explicitly say it doesn't support non-native. I am trying to run a tessel script via electron and am using a child process to spawn the tessel script. It works when I run electron from the command line, but not when I package the app.

```
Error: spawn tessel ENOENT
```